# What is the scope of `Bundle savedInstanceState`

Tags: android, bundle, activity-lifecycle

In android, we preserve the instance state of our activities by using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`.

Now in order to properly implement this it is necessary to have a **unique string key** for all variables stored inside `outState`.

I am curious of how unique I need to make this string.

1) Is the `Bundle` propagated via the Android OS to all active Activities - therefore all keys must be **Application & activity namespaced**?
(e.g. `com.twitter.www.mobile.LOGIN_ACTIVITY.is_logged_in`)

2) Is the `Bundle` only accessed by the Activity in which it was called- therefore all keys must only be **Application namespaced**?
(e.g. `com.twitter.www.mobile.is_logged_in`)

Comment: My suggestion is that you put the canonical name of the activity followed by the variable name, then there will be no possible confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle in a particular `Fragment` or `Activity` is unique only that `Fragment` or `Activity`. They are not propagated throughout the application. It's always good to be verbose/specific in your keys and variables to avoid confusion but you do not have to worry about accessing the wrong instance state bundle or key-value pair from a different activity or fragment.